# How do I get the TypeTag for an Array's element type?

Tags: arrays, scala

Given a variable `x of type X` <: Any, a type tag for X and pattern matching recovers that x is an `Array[_]` I would like to map over that array with a function that wants a type tag for the elements.

How do I do that, i.e. given I know a type tag is the type tag of an array, how do I get a type tag for it's type parameter at runtime?

Matching on the `typeOf[X].tpe` gets me the argument type but I don't know how to construct a type tag from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the compiler to provide it, but it needs to be where it is still known (so you couldn't use it if you pattern match an Any to find out what kind of thing it is - this happens at runtime where the types are erased):

```
val tag = implicitly[TypeTag[X]]
```

Or, maybe more clear, as an implicit parameter for the method where you are using it

```
def myOp[X <: Any](arr: Array[X])(implicit tag: TypeTag[X]) = ???
```